# Xamarin Forms webview not displaying on device

Tags: c#, android, ios, webview, xamarin

Ive developing a webview app in Xamarin.Forms over the last few days and ive been testing it on an android and iOS emulator and it seems to work just fine in the emulators but when i went and tried to test it on my own Android device, it just showed the xamarin splashscreen(im using the trial version at the moment) and then just transitioned to a blank white screen instead of the webview.

Does anyone have any ideas why it is doing this?

I will attach my code below:
**App.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace WebViewApp
{
    public class App() : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new WebPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

**WebPage.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace WebViewApp
{
    public class WebPage : ContentPage
    {
        private const string URL = "https://www.google.com";
        private const int PADDING_WIDTH = 0;

        private int paddingHeight;

        private WebView webView;

        public WebPage()
        {
            webView = new WebView
            {
                Source = URL,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };

            CheckDevice();

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(PADDING_WIDTH, GetPaddingHeight()),
                Chrildren = { webView }
            };
        }

        public int GetPaddingHeight()
        {
            return paddingHeight;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This will set the padding height for the webview when displayed
        /// <summary>
        /// <param name="pHeight">Set integer value for the padding height.</param>
        public void SetPaddingHeight(int pHeight)
        {
            paddingHeight = pHeight;
        }

        private void CheckDevice()
        {
            if(Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
            {
                SetPaddingHeight(0);
            }
            else if(Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
            {
                SetPaddingHeight(20);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

** UPDATE **
I am using a company website but I have been testing this app out with a number of different sites such as google, youtube, and amazon. It would seem that the only site that wont display on my device is my companies website(its a responsive website) but all of the others do.

Comment: Since it is only your company website that is not loading, have you looked through the output window, especially on Android, for lines that start with `Web Console` to see if there are any JavaScript console errors being output?

Comment: I dont see any that say Web Console but I am getting alot of chromium(1762):[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "..." coming up in the output window.

Comment: I would try giving the WebView a specific `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` just to test and make sure that is not the issue since when a `WebView` is put into certain layouts, it needs to ask its container what size it should be, while `StackLayout` always asks its children to find out what size it should be. I do not know why this would be different between an emulator and a real device though...

Comment: @hvaughan3 So i have added HeightRequest and a WidthRequest and it still doesnt work. I dont understand why it would display all other websites except my own. I have made a standalone Android webview project just to see if it works and it does.

Comment: Is your own site an internal or external site? Also are you hitting the site over https? If so, does the site us a self-signed certificate? If not, at least for iOS, you will need to add ATS exceptions.

Comment: So, everytime i run the program im getting this in the output window "[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated."" Any reason why this would be coming up?

Comment: Sounds like you have something like `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0">` where as it should be `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">` (note the comma after initial-scale=1.0 instead of the semi-colon). But I don't think this would mess up the entire page. Normally it would just skip over it. What API level are you running in?

Comment: @hvaughan3 Sorry for the delayed response. I believe it could be that aswell. I know im probably asking alot of what would be the best way of fixing such a thing?

Comment: Im getting these in the output window. I think this is the same thing you were talking about.

1. [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Viewport argument value "320px;" for key "width" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated."

2. [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated."

Any ideas?

Comment: No big deal. Sounds like you need to change it to: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">`. Note that I am not using semi-colons to separate anything and that the width value does not have `px` in it. [Check this out for more meta tag info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 7):

Since version 9, iOS will only allow your application to communicate with servers that implement best-practice security by default. Values must be set in Info.plist to enable communication with insecure servers.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads </key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: @Duggan Could you please flag this as the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

You must set the two properties HeightRequest and WidthRequest.

> WebView requires that HeightRequest and WidthRequest are specified
>   when contained in StackLayout or RelativeLayout. If you fail to
>   specify those properties, the WebView will not render.

Source: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/

Comment: in contrast to the document I tried the grid but it seems that the height and width request are required as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to display a webview in a Xamarin.Forms App.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace mynamespace
{
    public class WebsitePage : ContentPage
    {
        public WebsitePage(string url)
        {
            Label lbl_header = new Label
            {
                Text = "WebView",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            WebView webview = new WebView
            {
                Source = url,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
            this.Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                     webview
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```